# Existence of integrating factor for a complex 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold and $\theta\in\Omega^1(M)$ a (smooth) $1$-form. A clear consequence of Frobenius' theorem is that the necessary and sufficient condition for the *local* existence of functions $\phi,\psi$ such that $\theta=\psi d\phi$ is $d\theta\wedge\theta=0$. In particular this implies that every $1$-form on a $2$-manifold has an integrating factor.

Suppose now that $\theta=\theta_1+i\theta_2$ is a *complex-valued* differential $1$-form on $M$. What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of a pair $\phi,\psi$ of *complex-valued* functions such that $$ \theta=\psi d\phi? $$

The real Frobenius theorem does not seem to help here.

---

The context of this question is the existence of isothermal coordinates on two dimensional Riemannian manifolds. When $(M,g)$ is a two dimensional Lorentzian manifold, the Frobenius theorem provides an easy proof since we may write $ds^2=\theta_1^2-\theta_0^2$ for some orthonormal coframe $\theta_0,\theta_1$, which can be factored as $\theta_1^2-\theta_0^2=(\theta_1+\theta_0)(\theta_1-\theta_0)=\theta_+\theta_-$ and since each $1$-form has an integrating factor, this gives $ds^2=\psi_+\psi_- d\phi_+d\phi_-=\psi_+\psi_-(dx^2-dt^2)$ where $\phi_+=x+t$ and $\phi_-=x-t$.

The same proof does not work for positive definite metrics since then we have $ds^2=\theta_1^2+\theta_2^2$ and this can be factored as $ds^2=(\theta_1+i\theta_2)(\theta_1-i\theta_2)=\omega\bar\omega$. If it is also true that on a two dimensional space every complex $1$-form has an integrating factor, we are done.

There is a proof of the existence of isothermal coordinates this way in a [paper by Chern](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2032933), however it seems to me Chern wants to prove this theorem under minimal regularity assumptions and there are lots of analytical "nonsense" in the proof which makes it quite difficult for me to understand. What I am hoping if one is satisfied with a proof in the $C^r$ ($r\ge 1$) or even $C^\infty$ category, there is a proof that is similar to the Frobenius theorem in that it does not rely on any heavy-duty analytic or PDE-theoretic results.